# Use two different onClick listeners in React?

Tags: reactjs, onclicklistener

I am using 2 different event listeners in one li, I saw some of the solutions, but it didn't work for me. Where are the mistakes in my code?

```
getListItem(){
    let listItems = this.props.category.map((category1,index) =>
            <li style={{color: this.state.index==index?'red': 'black'}}
                className={this.state.index == index ? "tab-link current" : "tab-link"}
                value={category1.id}
                onClick={(e) => {
                this.onclick.bind(this, index);
                this.props.selectCategory;}}
                key={index}>
                {category1.name}
            </li>
    );
    return listItems;
}
```

so, these two event listners need to be used

```
onClick={this.onclick.bind(this, index)} value={category1.id}
onClick={this.props.selectCategory}

selectCategory(e){
    this.setState({
        category: e.target.value
    });
    var url='http://api';
    superagent
        .get(url)
        .query({page:this.state.selectCategory, category_id: e.target.value})
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .end ((error, response)=>{
        const startup=response.body.data.startup
        console.log(JSON.stringify(startup));
        this.setState({
            startup: startup,
            prevPage: response.body.data.prev_page,
            nextPage: response.body.data.next_page
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `this.props.selectCategory`?

Comment: this.props.selectCategory- select the menu category, like filtering the items. For instance, video companies or it companies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to call multiple functions from within the `onClick` listener, you don't want to do `this.onclick.bind();` because it does not call the function. Instead, it returns a function. You also don't need to bind `this` to the `onclick` function since arrow function syntax is used. It automatically binds `this`.

```
getListItem(){
    let listItems = this.props.category.map((category1,index) =>
            <li style={{color: this.state.index==index?'red': 'black'}}
                className={this.state.index == index ? "tab-link current" : "tab-link"}
                value={category1.id}
                onClick={(e) => {
                this.onclick(index);
                this.props.selectCategory(e);}}
                }}
                key={index}>
                {category1.name}
            </li>
    );
    return listItems;
},

onclick(index) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: `this.onclick.bind(this, index)` does not call the function. Instead it returns a function.

Comment: emmm to be honest, i don`t get your approach. Like i have  a function  onclick(index) {
        console.log('index', index);
        this.setState({index});
    }

Comment: Can you describe the problem when you run the code?

Comment: i have to different functions now i need to call that fucnctions, in one onClick listeners, but don`t know how

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. You could do `onClick={() => { this.onclick(); this.otherFunction(); }}`

Comment: i have no errors in console, it just when i use one of them onClick fucntion works, but when i use two onClick they don`t work. How i can use them 2 different func in one onClick listener

Comment: *"Try this"* is not a useful explanation of your solution. Please provide a proper explanation.

Comment: Look at my initial answer. You cannot do `this.onclick.bind();` because it does not call the function.

Comment: onClick={() => {
                    this.onclick(index);
                    this.props.selectCategory();}} , i did like that but now the second this.props.selectCategory function is not working ((

Comment: Are you passing a function prop named `selectCategory` from the parent component?

Comment: yes,   <StartUpPage selectCategory={this.selectCategory.bind(this)} />. In above i added the code of  selectCategory function.

Comment: ok, it worked just need to add (e) parameter like this   onClick={(e) => {
                    this.onclick(index);
                    this.props.selectCategory(e);}}